# JPA and Hibernate are driving me crazy not persisting my objects

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, netbeans, persistence

I have an existing java-JSF project that I was asked to add persistence to, using JPA and Hibernate, and of course, MVC. I'm using Postgres as a DBMS and Netbeans as my IDE.
I've done a lot of research and ended up being more confused that I was before I started, so here's what I've got so far:

My project needs to be a job listings website where a user can register and then apply for a job offer. But I'm plain stuck with just registering the user.
My View has a register.xhtml page that was built using JSF, there's a User.java class in my Model package and also a UserController bean in my Controller. register.xhtml makes a call to a register() method in the UserController bean, which is supposed to persist the User object.

I've configured my persistence.xml like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  
<persistence-unit name="TP5PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>  
<non-jta-data-source>tp5</non-jta-data-source>  
<class>model.User</class>  
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>  
<properties>  
  <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>  
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pootp5"/>  
</properties>  
</persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

I also created a PersistenceManager.java class that is a singleton and also has a singleton EntityManagerFactory inside it:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

public class PersistenceManager {

private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
private EntityManager em = null;
private static PersistenceManager instance = null;

private PersistenceManager(){
}

public static PersistenceManager getInstance() {
    if (instance==null){
        instance=new PersistenceManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
    if (emf == null){
        this.setEmf(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TP5PU"));
    }
        return emf;
}

public EntityManager getEm() {
    this.setEm(this.getEmf().createEntityManager());
    return em;
}

public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}


public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
}
```

Now, my UserController bean has this code:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import model.PersistenceManager;
import model.Usuario;

@ManagedBean (name="userController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable{

private String username;
private String password;
private String name;
private String lastname;
private String resume;
private PersistenceManager pm;
private EntityTransaction tx;

public UserController() {
    pm = PersistenceManager.getInstance();
    tx = pm.getEm().getTransaction();
}


public String register() {
    User user = new User(this.getUsername(), this.getPassword(), this.getName(), this.getLastname(), this.getResume());
    try {
        getPm().getEmf();
        getTx().begin();
        getPm().getEm().persist(user);
        getTx().commit();
        getPm().getEm().close();
        return "registered";
    }
    catch (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException e1){   
        if (getTx().isActive()){
            getTx().rollback();}
        getPm().getEm().close();
        return "duplicateuser";
    }
    catch (Exception e2){   
        if (getTx().isActive()){
            getTx().rollback();}            
        getPm().getEm().close();
        return "registrationerror";
    }
}

//all getters & setters
}
```

And all my User.java class has are a bunch of attributes and getter/setter methods:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(updatable=false)
protected long userID;
@Column(unique=true)
private String username;
private String password;
private String name;
private String lastname;
private String resume;

//and all the getters & setters needed for each attribute.
```

The register.xhtml page has a registration form (which I'm not including here because it's just a mess, with all i18n keys and stuff) that calls the UserController bean when the "Register" button is pressed:

If the register() method returns "registered", then there's a navigation rule that takes the user to the application login. If it returns "duplicateuser" then it's taken back to register.xhtml, and if it throws a different error message it also takes the user back to register.xhtml (yeah, there's not much logic involved in these, I needed to keep it simple).

The thing is, I get my User table created, but no User is persisted in it, and I get no error messages, exceptions or anything.
When debugging, my EntityTransaction object in the UserController bean shows the transaction as begun=true and then committed=true, so everything seems to be working. But I go check in my DB and the table got created but there are no users in it :(

Also, I'm wondering if I'm proceeding the right way when having PersistenceManager as a singleton and sticking all the persistence logic inside the UserController bean.
I'd be EXTREMELY thankful if someone could guide me a bit with this!
:)

Comment: Since you're coding with JSF, consider injecting managed entity managers with `@PersistenceContext` rather than creating your own EMF.

Comment: Thanks so much, Craig :) but I have tried to use injected entity managers, which leads to the need of using JTA, which makes my whole project explode :P I keep getting JTA errors, saying the EntityManagerFactory can't be created, and JTA TransactionManager related errors. I guess there's something not correctly configured, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: You don't need to use JTA to use injected entity managers; just use a JDBC datasource rather than a JTA datasource. As for the errors, maybe you should be investigating the root cause of those to see why it failed? Look at the last exception in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Your getEM() method creates a new EntityManager each and every time it is called.  This means that the entitymanager you use to start a transaction is not the same one you then call persist(user); on.  So the transaction commits, but isn't tied to the EM that contains your changes.

Using a static PM to hold EntityManagers is a bad idea, since EntityManagers are not thread safe themselves.  It might be good to use to obtain EntityManagers, but the register and other methods need to hold onto the entityManager directly and should close it when done.  The PM should also have a clean up method that closes its factory on shutdown or undeploy.